# Laravel Property [pdf] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have problem while trying to display PDF file from database, but it didn't find pdf column in database.

I try to call data but it's work

blade.php

```php
<input type="" name="book_id" value="{{request('id')}}">
<iframe src="{{ route('render.pdf',['file_name' => 'public/pdfs/'.$book->pdf]) }}" width="1000px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

controller

```php
public function recordAudio(Request $request)
{
    $data = Books::where('id', $request->id)
        ->with('authors', 'category', 'publisher', 'chapter')->first();
    return view('home.view-new-record', $data);
}
```

output didn't show

Comment: Have you tried adding `'pdf'` to  your `->with()` clause?

Comment: use `dd($data)` in your controller to check if `pdf` is there or not.

Comment: Can you add your model pdf relationship to your question.

Comment: Your code looks wrong. You're sending $data to the view, but using $book in the view. Try changing your code to something like:

$book = Books::where('id', $request->id)
        ->with('authors', 'category', 'publisher', 'chapter')->first();
    return view('home.view-new-record', compact('book'));

Answer (score 1):

First, use a `compact` method when you return `$data`.

```
public function recordAudio(Request $request)
{
    $data = Books::where('id', $request->id)
            ->with('authors', 'category', 'publisher', 'chapter')->first();
    return view('home.view-new-record', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `compact()` or `with()`

```
public function recordAudio(Request $request)
{
$data = Books::where('id', $request->id)
    ->with('authors', 'category', 'publisher', 'chapter')->first();
return view('home.view-new-record', compact('data'));
OR
return view('home.view-new-record')->with('data',$data);
}
```